# How to replace this with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm new to jQuery and I don't know what is the best function to replace this:

```
<span id="fcp-vicon" onClick="be_visible()"><img src="'.$path.'img/blueicons/hidden.jpg" alt="Cambiar a Modo Visible"/></span>
```

With this:

```
<span id="fcp-vicon" onClick="be_hidden()"><img src="'.$path.'img/blueicons/visible.jpg" alt="Cambiar a Modo Invisible"/></span>
```

The idea is that image works like a switch to toggle the visibility of other field.

Thank you very much.

---

Thanks, I need to change the span itself, so I need to change the related image and the inline onClick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to loktar's answer...

I assume what you want is an image that toggles the visibility of something else (lets say a div).

What you need is this html:

```
<span id="fcp-vicon"><img src="'.$path.'img/blueicons/visible.jpg" alt="Cambiar a Modo Invisible"/></span>
```

and something like this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // catch the click on the icon
    $('#fcp-vicon').click(function(){
        // toggle the visibility of the other element
        $('#id-of-other-element').toggle();
    });
});
```

With jquery there is no need for inline javascript! :)

## EDIT

Sorry, didn't realise you were changing the image each time...

Ok the best way to do this is to have two images in your span! :)

```
<span id="fcp-vicon">
    <img src="'.$path.'img/blueicons/visible.jpg" alt="Cambiar a Modo Invisible"/>
    <img src="'.$path.'img/blueicons/hidden.jpg" alt="Cambiar a Modo Invisible" style="display:none"/>
</span>
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // catch the click on the icon
    $('#fcp-vicon').click(function(){
        // toggle the visibility of the images contained in it
        $(this).find('img').toggle();
        // because the first image is showing and the second hidden
        // when you do this the first image will toggle to hidden
        // and the next one will toggle to visible.
    });
});
```

This might help: http://jsfiddle.net/tclayson/tPWNN/

Comment: More complete answer than mine, I just deleted mine +1

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't mean to undermine your answer at all, just add to it and explain a little bit. :)

Comment: Thanks, I need to change the span itself, so I need to change the related image and the inline onClick event.

Comment: heh np @Thomas Clayson, your answer is way more helpful :)

Comment: Oh I see! right... will edit (I didn't notice that the image was changed each time...)

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, At this moment I'm a bit confused with all this information, your help was very useful, now I'm going to test and see what happens.

Comment: have a look at the jsfiddle link, that should help you.

Comment: oh and you're welcome. :) if you need any more help then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to flip between two different images, not just show/hide a single image like the other answers show (I'm basing that on the fact that in your examples, you reference two different images.) If I've understood that correctly then you can do the following.

Add a class to your `span`, and remove the `onclick`:

```
<span id="fcp-vicon" class="visible">
    <img src="'.$path.'img/blueicons/hidden.jpg" alt="Cambiar a Modo Visible"/>
</span>
```

And use the following jQuery:

```
$("#fcp-vicon").click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass("visible")) {
       $(this).find("img").attr("src", "yourHiddenImage.jpg");
   }
   else {
       $(this).find("img").attr("src", "yourVisibleImage.jpg");
   }
   $(this).toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Here's a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/bBAt2/3/) based on the above code.

Comment: Thanks James, Can I use .find and .attr to change also 'onclick' and 'alt'?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use `onclick` anymore with this method.

Comment: I use onClick because the first time the user loads the page a query is executed to load the preference of the user: hidden or visible, then the user can toggle the state.

Comment: This means that the second image (yourHiddenImage.jpg) isn't loaded when you toggle between them, so the first time it may take a while to load. Not an issue necessarily, but still something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fcp-vicon").click(function(){


});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way

Use a DIV, set the dimensions to equal that of the image and use a background image. Use a class name to swap styles. Demo uses border color, just replace with `background-image`.

```
<div id="fcp-vicon"></div>
<div id="otherField">###</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fcp-vicon {
    border:1px solid #FFCC00;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#fcp-vicon.active {
   border:1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#fcp-vicon').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
    $('#otherField').toggle()    
})
```

Comment: Also a reasonable way to do this. :) There's lots of ways to toggle between two images on a web page, with not much reason to choose any specific way.